# Is it valid that two FIX messages are sent together in one go?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

My QuickFIX client is complaining that the body length is not expected.

After checking, it is found that it receives a message which actually contains 2 messages (2 different MsgTypes <35>). Also, 2 BeginStrings <8>

Is it a valid message?

The error is reported by QuickFIX, instead of my own code.
Hence, it looks like an invalid message to me although I cannot find any official doc, saying that it is not allowed.

Comment: Do you mean two consecutive messages? Can you paste the message?

Comment: @ChristophJohn Thanks for your reply. As it is client data, I cannot paste it directly here. Let me paste the structure here "8=FIXT.1.1[SOH]...10=xxx[SOH]8=FIXT.1.1[SOH]...10=xxx[SOH]". If these 2 messages come separately, the quickfix engine can handle that but it comes in one go.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I would expect that QuickFIX could parse the messages as long as the body length of the first message is correct. But on the other hand I am not that familiar with QuickFIX (C++ variant).

Comment: @ChristophJohn You should be right, finally I re-checked the message, it is found that the body length of the first message seems wrong. But would like to double-confirm that the body length is number of chars between {{}}. That is, 8=FIXT.1.1[SOH]9=xxx[SOH]{{body length calculation here}}10=xxx[SOH]. The definitions at the spec is quite vague. Btw, could you change your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as the solution

Comment: Your calculation is correct, added it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect that QuickFIX could parse the messages as long as the body length of the first message is correct.

You could check if the body length is correct by using the following:

> counting the number of characters in the message following the BodyLength (9) field up to, and including, the delimiter immediately preceding the CheckSum (10) field. ALWAYS SECOND FIELD IN MESSAGE. (Always unencrypted) For example, for message 8=FIX 4.4^9=5^35=0^10=10^, the BodyLength is 5 for 35=0^

Source: https://btobits.com/fixopaedia/fixdic44/index.html?tag_9_BodyLength.html

Answer (score 0):

Its completely depends on your fix engine whether to support multiple messages in one go or not.
Using BodyLength[9] and CheckSum[10] fields.
BodyLength is calculated starting from field starting after BodyLenght and
before CheckSum field.
CheckSum is calculated from ‘8= upto SOH before the checksum field.
Binary value of each character is calculated and compared to the LSB of the calculated value to the checksum value.
If the checksum has been calculated to be 274 then the modulo 256 value is 18 (256 + 18 = 274). This value would be transmitted a 10=018 where
"10="is the tag for the checksum field.